# Java Encoding: why the output is always the same?

Tags: java, encoding, groovy

For what reason I'm getting the same result:

```
 groovy -e "println 'Hello'.getBytes('windows-1251')"
```

result

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

and

```
 groovy -e "println 'Hello'.getBytes('UTF-8')"
```

result is the same

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Comment: Bcz it is returning the ascii value for the carector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English letters, numbers, standard symbols and so on in almost every encoding keep's same codes.

It's true for ASCII first page. Symbols with codes 0-127. If you try any other letters, result will differ.

```
groovysh "println 'Привет'.getBytes('windows-1251')"
[-49, -16, -24, -30, -27, -14]


groovysh "println 'Привет'.getBytes('UTF-8')"
[-48, -97, -47, -128, -48, -72, -48, -78, -48, -75, -47, -126]
```

Comment: `UTF-16` is one exception to this rule: `assert 'Hello'.getBytes('UTF-16') == [-2, -1, 0, 72, 0, 101, 0, 108, 0, 108, 0, 111]`

Comment: @tim_yates Nice point. Of corse. UTF-32 has the same issue to because minimal character size increases in more than 8-bit's encodings, and char won't fit in byte anymore. Moreover, I'm not sure, that there was no 8-bits encoding which breaks that rule. So I used "almost" in my answer.